# Why does the trend of the enthalpy of reaction per atom of carbon in hydrocarbons approach a near-constant value?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, hydrocarbons

I was looking at trends for enthalpies of hydrocarbons for a high school project and found an interesting paper regarding it, stating that the enthalpy per carbon atom approaches a constant. I'm thinking it has to do with the limited arrangement of bonds in hydrocarbons for bond dissociation energies, but I am not certain. Does anyone know a chemical explanation for why?
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444535634100057

[image: Referenced paper]

Comment: The limit increment value would be the sum of molar enthalpies for 2 C-H bonds and 1 C-C bond.

Comment: Thank you! I should've thought about it that way.

Comment: More significant than maths alone. If you take a chain long enough, ideally infinite, you realise that atom arrangement is the same at each position, and the sides are identical.